# Can you miss something or take damage and still get S-Rank?

Tags: thumper

I was under the impression that to get an S-Rank on any given "section" you'd have to make sure *nothing* was missed, and that you *never* got hit. However, in [this video](https://youtu.be/-xseAwMcco4?t=9m48s) (around 9:55, a bit after the time the link should drop you in), the player hits the wall and takes damage — at the end, though, they still get an S-Rank, both in that "section" (even though "no damage" isn't there) and in the level as a whole.

Am I missing something about how to get an S-Rank? Is it more about points, and less about missing or not missing thumps, and taking damage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Steam guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1255221235):

> To get that golden S, you have to hit at least 95% of stuff, factoring in the weighting, since hitting a thump pad means much more than hitting a ring.

There are more details on scoring and grading on the sections "Details on Scoring" and "Details on Grading," but it's clearly a matter of hitting *most* things, and avoiding *most* damage.